# Clang does not allow static_cast to parent class with template, while g++ and icc allow

Tags: c++11, g++, clang, static-cast

I am trying my C++11 code to see if all recent major compiler supports the features I used, and the following shortened code

```
#include <valarray>

struct T
{
    double vv[3];
};

class V : public std::valarray<T>
{
    public:
        auto begin()->decltype(std::begin(static_cast<std::valarray<T>>(*this)))
        {
            return std::begin(static_cast<std::valarray<T>>(*this));
        }
};

int main(void)
{

}
```

would compile with g++ 4.8.1(from Debian sid repository), Intel C++ compiler 13.1.1 20130313, but not Clang 3.3-2(from Debian sid repository).

The given error is:

```
test.cpp:11:73: error: no viable conversion from 'V' to 'std::valarray<T>'
    auto begin()->decltype(std::begin(static_cast<std::valarray<T>>(*this)))
                                                                    ^~~~~
```

However, code like this

```
namespace std
{
auto begin(V& vv) -> decltype(std::begin(static_cast<V::parent_t>(vv)))
{
    return std::begin(static_cast<V::parent_t>(vv));
}
}
```

would compile by all three compilers.

My question is: is the code itself allowed by the language standard, just Clang miscompiled it, or it is only supported by g++/icc extension? Or it is undefined behavior?

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that V is not complete in the declarators (including trailing return type) of its members, therefore the static_cast to its base class is not allowed there, as it would require a complete type.  I am more sure about the fact that it isn't complete then about that this disallows the cast.

Comment: Something you may try instead is `*static_cast<std::valarray<T>*>(this)`

Comment: or just use `decltype(begin(valarray<T>()))`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but clang seems happier with the more common usage pattern of `*static_cast<std::valarray<T>*>(nullptr)`

Comment: i don't see why it would require a complete type. an incomplete type can be passed to reference parameters (copy or move constructors).

Comment: @NateKohl, `declval` exists so you don't need to do that:  `std::declval<std::valarray<T>&>()`

Comment: Why are you doing a `static_cast` to a value type anyway, not a reference or pointer? That creates a new temporary object, so the iterators are invalidated immediately!

Answer (score 0):

The code very dangerous and needs to be fixed even for GCC and ICC.

You're doing a `static_cast` to a value type, not a reference or pointer. That creates a new temporary `valarray` object, so the `const` overload of `begin` gets called (probably not what you intended), and the iterator returned by `begin()` refers to the temporary which goes out of scope immediately, so the returned iterator is invalid and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

The code will compile like this:

```
    auto begin()->decltype(std::begin(std::declval<std::valarray<T>&>()))
    {
        return std::begin(static_cast<std::valarray<T>&>(*this));
        /* cast to reference type!    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
    }
```

The `decltype` doesn't need to cast `this`, it just needs to know the type of calling `std::begin` on a `valarray<T>`, so it doesn't matter if the type is incomplete because you don't need a cast.

In the body of the function the type is considered complete anyway, so the cast is valid.